# Azure How to find maximum NICs that can be attached to a VM?

Tags: azure

I am looking for REST API that gives me the maximum number of NICs that can be attached to a VM based on the VM Size.

I have searched for Azure REST API references, but I couldn't find any API. I am able to use the below API to get max. data disks that can be attached to VM, I also need to get the max. NICs. Any help how I can get this information?

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/westus/vmSizes?api-version=2016-03-30

Sample output:
{
"name": "Standard_DS1_v2",
"numberOfCores": 1,
"osDiskSizeInMB": 1047552,
"resourceDiskSizeInMB": 7168,
"memoryInMB": 3584,
"maxDataDiskCount": 4
},

Answer (score 0):

well, its dependent on the size of the VM. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-general) article, it has got everything you need in it.

Comment: Thank you. I have seen this article. I need to get the information programmatically and display it for the user. I use REST APIs to do the integration with Azure, so looking for REST API to get the max. NICs information.

Comment: @srinu259 same here

Comment: Did anyone ever find and answer to how to get this information via API?